# How to import/use package installed with Composer?

Tags: php, docker, package, composer-php

I'm just getting started with PHP and I ran into a small problem.

I've downloaded a package using `composer require <package_name>` and now I'm not sure how to access it from my .php file. I tried bunch of things but I couldn't make it work.

I'm trying to use this package: https://packagist.org/packages/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php

EDIT:
This is the code I use to test:

```
<?php

use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiate app
$app = AppFactory::create();

// Add Error Handling Middleware
$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, false, false);

// Register routes
$routes = require __DIR__ . '/../app/routes.php';
$routes($app);

$swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00";
$phoneUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
try {
    $swissNumberProto = $phoneUtil->parse($swissNumberStr, "CH");
    var_dump($swissNumberProto);
} catch (\libphonenumber\NumberParseException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}

// Run application
$app->run();
```

And it says: `Undefined type 'libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil'.`

Comment: A usable start would be `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: I edited it, please check it.

Comment: You might want to double check your `composer.json`. I have no issues running it.

Comment: what should I look for at the composer.json? As I said I'm getting started with PHP and have no experience.

Comment: In that case, please start reading here -> https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Comment: At the require in the composer.json there is this package. I don't know what else to look for?

Comment: Which version of that package did you install? How is this problem related to Docker? If it is not, please remove that tag